# View model Property setter not hit when dependency property updated

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a user control with a dependency property:

```
public ObservableCollection<Exclusion> SelectedExclusions
{
    get
    {
        return (ObservableCollection<Exclusion>)GetValue(SelectedExclusionsProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(SelectedExclusionsProperty, value);
    }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedExclusionsProperty =
       DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(TimeSeriesChart.SelectedExclusions), 
                                   typeof(ObservableCollection<Exclusion>), 
                                   typeof(TimeSeriesChart), 
                                   new PropertyMetadata(default(ObservableCollection<Exclusion>)));
```

I am adding a selected exclusion to this collection on key down:

```
 protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
 {
   if(e.Key == Key.Delete)               
   {                       
     this.SelectedExclusions.Add(this.ExclusionProviders[0].Exclusions[this.hitTestInfo.DataSeriesIndex]);                                                         
   }                 
 }
```

In the view model I have this property & backing variable:

```
 private ObservableCollection<TimeSeriesLibraryInterop.Exclusion> selectedExclusionsToDelete = new ObservableCollection<TimeSeriesLibraryInterop.Exclusion>();

 public ObservableCollection<TimeSeriesLibraryInterop.Exclusion> SelectedExclusionsToDelete
   {
     get
      {
        return this.selectedExclusionsToDelete;
      }
      set
       {
         this.selectedExclusionsToDelete = value;       
         this.RaisePropertyChanged();                          
       }
     }
```

Finally the binding in the view:

```
   <userControl1 SelectedExclusions="{Binding SelectedExclusionsToDelete, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The dependency property collection is initialised and populated however the view model property setter is never hit when the dependency property collection changes (Add). I have no binding errors in the output window. Is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Looks like you're adding an item to the collection rather than replacing the collection. You won't hit the vm collection property's setter that way. If you want to listen for changes to the collection, you'll need to handle the `SelectedExclusionsToDelete.CollectionChanged` event in your viewmodel. Alternatively, I think you could make it a two-way binding and assign a new `ObservableCollection` to `this.SelectedExclusions` on `OnKeyDown`. That would hit the setter.

Comment: @ Ed Plunkett, thanks yes just needed to new up the colelction prior to adding...

Comment: Cool, I'll put that in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're adding an item to the collection rather than replacing the collection. You won't hit the vm collection property's setter that way.

If you want to your viewmodel to respond to items being added to the `SelectedExclusionsToDelete` collection, the viewmodel will need to handle the `SelectedExclusionsToDelete.CollectionChanged` event. "Properly" handling that event (remove, add, move, clear, etc.) is a real hassle, but if it's not a giant collection you can often get away with something quick and dirty: Treat any change as a whole new collection. I think that's exactly the case you've got, too.

Alternatively, for an even quicker and dirtier approach, I think you could make it a two-way binding by default and have the control assign a new `ObservableCollection` to `this.SelectedExclusions` in `OnKeyDown`. The binding will pass it back to the viewmodel and hit the setter.